# recursive creating a list of connected nodes in network issue - with python

Tags: python, recursion, networkx

I've create a simple graph using the networkx package in python, as demonstrated in the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

G=nx.Graph()

G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_node(4)
G.add_node(5)
G.add_node(6)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(1,5)
G.add_edge(4,6)
```

then, I've defined a function which receives the following parameters:

- G : the network
- z : an empty list
- node : the node to start from

recursive function:

```
def recurse(G, z , node):
    z.append(node)
    n = list(set(G.neighbors(node)) - set(z)) 
    if len(n) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        for i in n:
            if i not in z:
                return z.extend(recurse(G, z, i))
```

and have tested the function with the following code:

```
z = []
f = recurse(G,z,1)
```

which was suppose to return the following list --> [1,2,3,5]

but am getting the following error when trying to execute the code:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-143154073995> in <module>()
     14 
     15 z = []
---> 16 f = recurse(G,z,1)

<ipython-input-91-143154073995> in recurse(G, z, node)
     11         for i in n:
     12             if i not in z:
---> 13                 return z.extend(recurse(G, z, i))
     14 
     15 z = []

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I've printed every step of the function and have noticed that the list is built up until it has the following values --> [1,2,3] and then it fails

Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: If you give your variables sensible names it might be easier to understand what is going on.. Eg. rename z to seen, then ask yourself why you're adding the same elements multiple times, what happens when you return an empty list, and if it can be global for the recursion or if perhaps you'll need a fresh copy for each branch of the recursion..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.extend` returns `None` instead of list extended.

Try this:

```
z.extend(recurse(G, z, i))
return z
```